# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout after migration to androidx

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I made a migration to `AndroidX`, then I'm getting an error if I try to run the project into an emulator with `API 29`.

There is no problem in emulators/real devices with `API 28` and previous.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ [...]}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in [...]:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Binary XML file line #23 in [...]:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: check the xml's - if there are 'android' tags you should change them to 'androidx'.

Comment: I've tried to fix the xml, but the xml in error (if I'm not wrong) "layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode" isn't in my project. but in the androidx.appcompat library.

Comment: Can you provide the XML part that fails?

Comment: Solved. Similar to the below answer, I've noticed in the very long stack trace this info: "at com.mikepenz.iconics.context.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)". I've updated the Iconics library and the app runs correctly. Thanks to all.

Comment: I am getting the same issue after update below version for Iconics library
implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.2.5"
 implementation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.5'
can you please help me if you get to resolve it.
@AlessioPapazzoni

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Calligraphy Library, make sure to update to the 3+ version as mentioned by the author here: [Issue #475](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/475)

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
}
```